# Show linestring geometry as centroid of a joined polygon layer with QGIS and spatialite ASSVG

Tags: qgis, spatialite, svg

In QGIS, I have a linestring and a polygon layer which are joined and I want to show the linestring as a centroid in the polygon layer.
I used ASSVG() from SpatiaLite but wont't get a correct SVG.

In spatialite AsSvg(geometry):
`M 57 0 L 58 0 59 0 60 0 61 ... 581 0 582 0 583 0`
I tried a minimal SVG, but Inkscape won't load it:
`<svg height="200" width="700"><path d="M 57 0 L 58 0 59 0 60 0 61 ... 581 0 582 0 583 0"/></svg>`
Where is the mistake?

Last, I want to load the SVG it in QGIS as centroid:
centroid / marker / svg
Can I use the SVG column directly?
`"svg_column"`
Or do I need something like this?
`'base64:'|| to_base64("svg_column")`

Answer (score 1):

I lastly managed to solve the problem myself. A less simpler <svg ... part and the size of the svg in qgis was far to small. 'base64:'|| to_base64("svg_column") was the correct way.